# Playframework dynamic form handling

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.3

Hallo guys im new to the playframework and run into a little problem
regarding form handling.
Here is my view

```html
<form action="@routes.Account.changeemail()" method="Post">
 email:<input name ="email"> 
 <button type="submit" name="action" value="Change_email">save</button>

  <br />
 </form>
 <form action="@routes.Account.changepassword()" method="Post">
  
  password:<input name ="password"> 
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="change_password">save</button>
 
 </form>
 <br />
```

And here is my controller

```
public static Result changeemail(){

final DynamicForm form = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
Logger.info(form.get("email"));
return TODO;}

public static Result changepassword(){
final DynamicForm forms = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
Logger.info(forms.get("password"));
return TODO;}
```

Here the routes:

```
GET    /account                   controllers.Account.accountview()
POST   /account                   controllers.Account.changeemail()
POST   /account                   controllers.Account.changepassword()
```

The problem is if i press the Change_email button it does the right thing, but if i press the password button it is doing the changeemail action , even if it should handle the changepasswort action. I checked it with the firefox networkanalysis and it seems that it is sending the correct action.

In forward thanks for the help

Greetings Alex

Comment: Could you post the routes file as well? The result you're reporting seems a little bit odd, might be something in there that's hiding?

Comment: The routes which regard to this problem:
GET      /account    controllers.Account.accountview()
POST   /account                       controllers.Account.changeemail()
POST   /account                       controllers.Account.changepassword()          added it also in the orginal post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your routes, the order is important. Your router always takes the first `POST /account` which executes the `changeemail()` action. You can't have `POST /account` for two different actions. It should be :

```
GET    /account                          controllers.Account.accountview()
POST   /account/change-email             controllers.Account.changeemail()
POST   /account/change-password          controllers.Account.changepassword()
```